# Constructing a mid using signals from another asset

Tags: high-frequency, market-making, prediction

When delta-neutral market making it is important to construct a mid price. Often the mid price of the asset you are trading is influenced by another (correlated) asset. What methodologies would you recommend to combine the returns of the leading asset into the mid price for the asset I am trading? Linear regression (var) models spring to mind.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide some more background on why you would want to use another correlated asset to calculate a mid price for the given asset rather than using bid-ask prices? Surely this methodology falls apart in practice as correlations can diverge suddenly and sharply?

Comment: @Bob Jansen moved your comment but didn't move mine: Not the OP but using the instantaneous bid/ask makes sense if there's a structural pricing relationship (e.g. ES vs SPY, 6E vs EUR/USD), but it's a different problem from if they're just correlated (e.g. ES vs NQ). Also, instantaneous bid/ask doesn't capture prediction alpha. Moreover, just because there's distribution shift doesn't mean you shouldn't forecast. Such changes can be handled by building covariate shift into the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a prior that returns of one asset should lead the other, you could construct features with the same direction as the returns of the leading asset and constrain the weights of those features with [nonnegative least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares).

Comment: I have the features, but what model/ methodology would you use to create the signal? Is a linear regression or similar enough? seems crude

Comment: As mentioned, NNLS isn't bad. I've seen many researchers linearize the response by building in certain decay, lag, scaling, or other structure into the features before using NNLS.